# replace column value + results with other column + value

Tags: php, mysql

In order to go multi-language, we have this setting:

1. all language fields are stored in the same record in the MySQL table
2. on cookie-language-id we need to replace English (id 1) to France (id 2)
3. when cookie says: langID = 2, we need to change English to France:

> ```
> values like: title (as in: SELECT title FROM ...)
> and, change: $title (as in: $title=$rows["title"]; )
> ```

to:

- title_fr
- and: $title_fr

is there any PHP/quick solution for this?

Comment: Can you show an example of what the table structure looks like? Ideally with a couple rows of example data. As it is now, we have to just guess where you store a langID in the database and/or what format that is in.

Comment: Just for the record, both answer below are equally good! Amazing jobs from @obe and @alexander.polomodov!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
<?
$arrMapCookieToLang = [
    1 => "",
    2 => "fr",
    3 => "es",
];

function langify($item, $cookieLangId = null) {
    global $arrMapCookieToLang;

    if (empty($cookieLangId)) {
        $cookieLangId = 1;
        if (array_key_exists("cookie-language-id", $_COOKIE)) {
            $cookieLangId = $_COOKIE["cookie-language-id"];
        }
    }

    $langCode = $arrMapCookieToLang[$cookieLangId];
    if (empty($langCode)) return $item;
    return "{$item}_{$langCode}";
}

$sql = "SELECT ".langify("title")." FROM ...";
$title = $rows[langify("title")];

// OR:
$sql = "SELECT ".langify("title")." AS title FROM ...";
$title = $rows["title"];
```

However note that having a column per language is probably not a very good practice. You should probably go in a direction like alexander.polomodov suggested.

Also, even if you choose to continue with the current structure - consider putting $arrMapCookieToLang and the langify() function in a class (global variables and functions are evilish)

Comment: Thank you @obe! This is the one implemented. alexander.polomodov's answer worked great as well, but this one was easier to use. Thanks again! Great job there!

Comment: np :) but if this system needs to be maintained in the future then I highly recommend alexander's solution. A small time investment now can save you a lot of time and frustration in the future... It's often really worthwhile to invest in a solid infrastructure...

Comment: Noted! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can create language mapping like this:

```
// lets assume that we need not only title but also description
$lang2Fields = array(
    1 => ['title' => 'title', 'description' => 'description'], // en
    2 => ['title' => 'title_fr', 'description' => 'description_fr'], // fr
    3 => ['title' => 'title_ru', 'description' => 'description_ru'], // ru
    // ... other languages
);

// try to get language id from cookie
$defaultLanguage = 1; // en
$language = !empty($_COOKIE["langID"]) ? $_COOKIE["langID"] : $defaultLanguage;

$fields = !empty($lang2Fields[$language]) ?
    $lang2Fields[$language] : $lang2Fields[$defaultLanguage];

$titleField = $fields['title'];
$descriptionField = $fields['description'];

// later we can use these field names into your queries

// $sql = "SELECT ".$titleField.", ".$descriptionField." FROM ...";
// $$titleField = $rows[$titleField];
```

Comment: Thanks very much alexander.polomodov! As commented above, your answer was just as good, but more work to implement. But I will use it in the future for sure. Great learning here from you guys!